# Opening Pydev editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor, pydev

I am a newbie to using pydev in eclipse. How do I start working in the editor. I have done all the configs. and project set up but just can't use the editor. What are the steps involved? Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

If everything is set up you should be able to follow these steps:

- Right click on your project and select `New -> PyDev Module`
- Enter a name for your module and click `Finish`
- The editor will open and you can start coding

Comment: Thanks ellak. It seems to be headed in the right direction but the editor gives a big red X with: "Failed to create the part's controls."

Comment: It sounds like your PyDev installation is corrupt. Try installing a new one.